# Need to find a simple word the opposite of voice .. not voiceless

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

I am trying to find a term for someone who participates a lot in meetings, organizations etc. but they never say anything or they don't have a real voice.  So their appearance is more for show. The organization doesn't want to hear their voice.  The opposite of Voice but not voiceless.

Comment: You mean like Nixon's ***silent** majority*?

Comment: *(passive) **observer**?* We don't normally say things like *He is a voice,* so what's the exact context where you want to use an "antonym"?

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence where the word would be used ?

Comment: they participate a lot but they never say anything.  how does that work?

Comment: The organization doesn't want to hear your voice; it just wants to see your face?

Comment: Thanks.  I meant more someone who shows up to meetings but has no voice because the person learning the meeting doesn't give any voice.  They simply hold meetings out of compliance and people show up ... hence they claim large participation numbers.  It is for a presentation I am working on so I don't need the word in a sentence as much as a way to describe this type of "participant".  Passive might just work. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think that people who shows in meetings, without any kind of interaction can be defined passive audience